# java spark 1.6 csv file

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

i'am using spark 1.6 for read csv file, coding for java

```
URL resource = Main.class.getResource("GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry.csv");
    File filePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local","Java Spark example");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(filePath.getAbsolutePath());
    dataFrame.show();
```

but ....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org

what i doing wrong? for my version no csv parser? path is correct
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `format("csv")` for  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") and adding dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

result code:

```
 URL resource = Main.class.getResource("GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry.csv");
    File filePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local","Java Spark example");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(filePath.getAbsolutePath());
    dataFrame.show();
```

worked!